# How to remove overlapping of image slide show over my Navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, vs-web-site-project

I have created this website and everything seems to work but the only problem is my image slider is overlapping over my navbar. I have tried almost everything to fix it... but it seems to be not working... I have put z-index: 1000; for my navbar and z-index: 1; for my slider. And it is the same.

It would be appreciated a lot if you solve this!

Thanking you, Gabriel!

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.slides');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slides img');

// Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

// Counter
let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

// Button Listeners

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

carouselSlide.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone') {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone') {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
});

const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-links")[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
});

  function HideScrollbar() {
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = `body::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`;
    document.head.appendChild(style);
  }
```

```css
/*  */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}

/* This is to remove the scroll 
bar but it is functional */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.scrollbar-hidden::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #a9a9a9;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav h1,
nav ul {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Sections */
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.section1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../Basic/components/home.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.section2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../Basic/components/temple.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: text 2s 1;
}
.section3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../Basic/components/contact.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: cover;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 72%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: none;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* ---------- Navbar ---------- */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}

/* Cursor */
.cursor {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  30% {
    letter-spacing: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  85% {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .button {
    display: none;
  }
  @keyframes text {
    display {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

/* --------- Image Slider --------- */
.slider {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 71.5%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160%;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- title -->
        <title>Gab's Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" 
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Main Header -->
        <header>
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="brand-title">Gab's Web</div>
                <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#templates">Template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <div class="bubble"></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- Pages -->
        <main>
            <section id="home" class="section1">Home
                <div class="button">
                    <a id="btn1" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SalOP2ZiO9fK-yxPtYF3A" class="btn">Channel</a>
                    <a id="btn2" href="#" class="btn">Sponsor</a>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="templates" class="section2">
                <!-- Image Slider Start -->
                    <div class="slider">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
                        <div class="slides">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-5.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-4.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-5.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="../Basic/components/img-1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
                        </div>
                    <!-- Image Slider End -->
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="contact" class="section3">Contact</section>
            <!-- Buttons -->
        </main>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../Temple1/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `z-index:1` (or whatever you need to it to be) on the `<header>` element should solve this.